# Replaced fragment is not destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments, replace, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

EDIT:
After some more tinkering around, I found out the reason for my previous problem (see below. TL;DR: I'm trying to pass a `Bundle` from an activity to its fragment by replacing the fragment) is that when replacing fragments like this:

```
    AddEditActivityFragment fragment = new AddEditActivityFragment();
    Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.add_edit_fragment, fragment)
        .commit();
```

the replaced fragment *does not* get destroyed (as it should be according to [a](https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/fragment-lifecycle-during-fragment-transaction/) [bunch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783984/lifecycle-when-calling-the-fragment-replace-or-open-new-activity) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032113/difference-between-add-replace-with-fragments-lifecycle) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032113/difference-between-add-replace-with-fragments-lifecycle)), which I verified by overriding and adding logging to `onPause`, `onStop`, `onDestroyView`, `onDestroy`, etc. None of them are called. 
Calling `popBackStackImmediate` also does nothing.
What can I do?

Previous question title: 
"Setting FloatingActionButton icon dynamically with setImageDrawable doesn't have any effect."
I have a `FAB` inside a fragment (called AddEditFragment), that serves to save user input to database.
To differentiate between editing rows from the DB and creating new ones, I had its icon set either a "send" icon or a "save" icon.
By default, the button is set to "send":

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_edit_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/add_edit_toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"/>
```

I used to set the icon to "save" by implementing an interface in my fragment, which serves to pass data from the containing activity to the fragment, using this method:

```
    @Override
public void receiveData(Serializable data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "receiveData: called");
    mFoodItem = (FoodItem) data;
    if (mFoodItem != null) {
        mEditMode = true;
        fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_save_white_24dp));
        utilDisplayFoodItem();
    }
}
```

The call the `setImageDrawable` worked fine and changed the icon from "send" to "save" properly. 



Here is when I run into trouble.

I am trying to remove my AddEditFragment class' dependency on my AddEditActivity class, by removing said interface implementation and passing the data required by the fragment via `Bundle`:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starts");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit);

    AddEditActivityFragment fragment = new AddEditActivityFragment();
    Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
    boolean editMode = arguments != null;
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.add_edit_fragment, fragment)
            .commit();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close_white_24dp);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle((editMode) ? "Edit Item:" : "Create Item:");
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ends");
}
```

In this context, I removed `receiveData` method from the fragment, and placed this line:

```
fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_save_white_24dp));
```

in various likely places in my fragment class (the likeliest being inside its `onCreateView` method). 

It doesn't seem to have any effect. My cases are:

1. *Just adding said `setImageDrawable` call* - sets icon to "save" in both add/edit modes, but then I have no "send" icon.
2. *Setting either case dynamically (`setImageDrawable` call is inside `if` block)* - icon is set to "send" in both add/edit modes.
3. *Removing default "send" icon from XML, then setting either case dynamically* - icon is set to "send" in both add/edit modes.
4. *Removing default icon from XML, then setting only to "save" dynamically (no `if` block)* - sets icon to "save" in both add/edit modes, but then I have no "send" icon.

It seems the `setImageDrawable` call, which worked perfectly in my `receiveData` interface method, **doesn't have any effect** (at least when an icon is already set, or when inside `if` block).

 
 
I'm at a loss and would appreciate any help!

In reply to @ColdFire:

```
        @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: starts");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_edit, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null) {
        mFoodItem = (FoodItem) arguments.getSerializable(FoodItem.class.getSimpleName());
        if (mFoodItem != null) {
            mEditMode = true;
            // Tried calling setImageDrawable here
        }
    }

    // Tried calling setImageDrawable here

    if (!mEditMode) {
        // If adding an item, initialize it for right now's date and time
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        mFoodItem.setDate(now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        mFoodItem.setTime(now.getTimeInMillis() / Constants.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    utilDisplayFoodItem();
    utilSetOnClickListeners();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    // Tried calling setImageDrawable here

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ends");
    return view;
}
```

I should mention that everything else that depends on the Bundle data works correctly.

Comment: post the code in which you handle the bundle data in fragment

Comment: Now included in question

Answer (score 0):

You might want to clear back stack by using the following method

```
private void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
        manager.popBackStackImmediate(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

You might want to [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529499/problems-with-android-fragment-back-stack), Thanks

This will only destroy the current fragment to be replaced. If you want to destroy all you might want to read this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186433/clear-back-stack-using-fragments)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me (nor do the questions you linked).
The problem isn't that the fragment isn't replaced, but that the replaced fragment isn't destroyed, so I keep seeing some of its views (FAB specifically) on top of the new fragment, meaning it is still there.

Comment: @HaslElus no idea, it's been a long time. Sorry